# How did Japan do private era name and regnal name prior to Taika?

Tags: japan, medieval-japan, classical-japan, ancient-japan

How did Japanese private era names (shinengo, 私年号/私年號) and regnal names (non era name systems) work before the nengo system? I know starting with Taika they had public era names (公年号/公年號) created by the ruler (Taika, Hakuchi, Shucho, Taiho and so on), but before that (also between 654-686, 686-701) it was complicated with there being regnal name **[see note 1]** or single/multiple private era names (e.g. Hōkō [法興], a private era name spanned from 591-621), during one rule.

I saw some thing like "Emperor Tenmu was born in about Jomei 3 (631)", "Emperor Shomu was born in Monmu 2 (698)", I think these are non era name regnal years. Also, private era names such as Hakuho (白鳳), Suzaku (朱雀) is often mentioned in books, such as "Prince Toneri was born in Hakuho 5 (676)", "In Suzaku 2 (672), Jinshin war happened".

How exactly did they decide when an regnal name (among private era name) started and ended without using the system in *Nihon Shoki* to decide them?

**Notes:**

**[note 1]:** The first year of a ruler 's reign will be considered as *[ruler name] 1*, 2nd year will be considered as *[ruler name] 2*, and so on.

**Research efforts:**

I think, if a ruler ascend to the throne on the next year the previous ruler died and stopped reigning, that year that ruler ascend to the throne will be considered as *[ruler name] 1*, However, such situation's regnal name will start on that year's the 1st day of the 1st lunar month, rather than the day the emperor ascend to the throne. If a ruler ascend to the throne on the same year as previous ruler died and stopped reigning, that **next** year (on the 1st day of the 1st lunar month) that ruler ascend to the throne will be considered as *[ruler name] 1* and that year the ruler ascend to the throne (even after such ruler ascend to the throne) will be still called *[name of previous ruler] [year order]*, instead of the year and date a ruler ascend to the throne (unless this happened due to an abdication, e.g. Emperor Kotoku [between July 12, 645 to July 17, 645, before the establishment of era name system]). I think so because the system I mentioned works similarly to the one on pre-[Zhongtong](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%AD%E7%B5%B1) Chinese Yuan Dynasty regnal years and era names. Emperor Ruizong of Yuan ascend to the throne in response to the death of Emperor Taizu in 1227, but such regnal name started in 1228, Taizong Regent Töregene Khatun Empress (r. 1242-1245) died and stopped regent in 1245 and Emperor Dingzong ascend to the throne in 1246, but the corresponding regnal name in 1246 is **ONLY** Dingzong 1 (and **WITHOUT** Empress Töregene 5). According to the research efforts I said, I think the answer is conculsions I mentioned above.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  The theoretical model you articulate seems plausible, but where have you looked so far?  At first glance this appears to be covered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name) "no era names were designated between 654 and 686. The system was briefly reinstated by Emperor Tenmu in 686, but was again abandoned upon his death about two months later."

Comment: I saw some thing like "Emperor Tenmu was born in about Jomei 3 (631)", "Emperor Shomu was born in Monmu 2 (698)", I think these are non era name regnal years.

Comment: Already moved. In addition, I added more remarks.